# crontab systax for automatically copying file if not exists

Tags: file, cron, copy, exists

I use Ubuntu.
I want: Every hour, **crontab** checks: *if* on certain folder doesn't exists a file named blabla.doc, *then* copy it from another folder or download from website.

Similar like this:

```
* 0 * * * if not exists ~/www/blabla.doc then cp ~/backup/blabla.doc ~/www
```

Comment: Please put the code portion of your question into a code block.

Comment: Meanwhile, what have your tried so far and what were your results?

Comment: Not worked or nothing is happened. :(

Comment: I'm answering you, but in general, please put more effort into researching your question.  It appears as if you've done next to no research before asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your logic into a shellscript, and have `cron` execute that script.

```
* 0 * * * /bin/sh /home/user/cronscripts/move_my_www_file.sh
```

Then, your `move_my_www_file.sh` might look like:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ ! -e "path/to/your/file" ]; then   # if not exists
    cp ...
fi
```